# Store Large volume data

Tags: stellar-core

Is there any way to send data over memo more than 28 bytes. As I have done one experiment to send data greater than 28 bytes using SHA256 algorithm but it can not be decoded. So any method regarding this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing data on the blockchain?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/670/storing-data-on-the-blockchain)